Is it possible to send SPL token from a wallet to another wallet using laravel?
I want to try writing code to send SPL tokens from one wallet to another. I've tried it before using a JS framework, but now I want to try using Laravel. I managed to create a wallet connection, but whenever I import ESM for SPL token, I always get a uuid error. Does anyone know about this? I actually just need an answer on whether it's possible or not. Thank you if you're willing to answer.

can you post your code snippet here? so we can figure out what's going on without any code snippet it's hard to say why you getting uuid error.
